# Custom interaction Plotly in ggplot - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have a massive dataset that makes graph plotting tedious and complex.

Assume this simplified dataset:

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.table(continent = c(rep("America",3), rep("Europe",4)),
           state = c("USA", "Brazil", "Chile", "Italy", "Swiss", "Spain", "Greece"),
           X = rnorm(7, 5, 1),
           Y = rnorm(7, -13, 1),
)

df$X_sd = sd(df$X)
df$Y_sd = sd(df$Y)
```

Consider having > 30 levels for "state", which makes it very difficult to show them with different colours or shapes.

I have decided to use `plotly` to show this dataset.

Here what I have done:

```
p <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=X,
              y=Y, 
              fill = continent,
              color = continent)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = X - X_sd,
                     xmax = X + X_sd),
                 size = 0.5,
                 alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Y - Y_sd,
                    ymax = Y + Y_sd),
                size = 0.5,
                alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_point(shape=21,
    color="black",
    size=3) +
  theme_bw()

ggplotly(p)
```

However, the interactive window does not show information regarding the country, which is what I want to achieve.
In fact, every time I go over a point, I would like to have a window that shows: Continent, Country, X and Y (and in case I will have more factors or columns, I would like to be to include them too).

I have tried to add `shape = country` within the aesthetics, but 1) there are not enough shapes, 2) it fights against my decision of having shape = 21 for `geom_point()`, and 3) it adds a huge legend which I don't want.

How can I personalize the interaction window of `plotly` without adding extra and not-needed aesthetics?

Furthermore, I have tried to remove the legend by using:

```
guides(fill="none", color="none")+
```

or by

```
%>%  hide_legend()
```

but either way, do not work. How can I remove the legend?

Comment: ```theme(legend.position = "none")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add `label` in your `aes` to add factors like `state`. You can do that multiple times. You can use the following code:

```
p <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(label = state,
             x=X,
             y=Y, 
             fill = continent)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = X - X_sd,
                     xmax = X + X_sd),
                 size = 0.5,
                 alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Y - Y_sd,
                    ymax = Y + Y_sd),
                size = 0.5,
                alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_point(shape=21,
             color="black",
             size=3) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

ggplotly(p)
```

Output:

[image]